# Email Sends object creating empty records when email is sent from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated our Marketing Cloud environment with Salesforce CRM, but we're not able to see the data in the Email Sends object when a Email is sent from Marketing cloud.

We created a salesforce data extension and imported the contacts. When sending the email from marketing cloud through salesforce sends, a new record gets created on the CRM on the Email Sends object, but it's kinda empty. (no contact id or other info is put into the new created record).

Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: Are you tracking Individual Email Results (set in the tracking detail of the Config)?  Does the job ID overall tracking show up on that email send record in Salesforce?  What data are you expecting to show up?  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_manage_settings.htm&type=5

Comment: I am expecting to see the Send Definition fields of the Email Sends object populated once an email is send from marketing cloud through Salesforce Sends. Here's a screen of what I am expecting to see populated (in particular, i'm expecting the "Contact" field to be populated with the contact that received the email. ) https://ibb.co/vX1QKk1

Answer (score 1):

The send definition will encompass the whole send.  Therefore unless this was a send originating from the CRM by clicking the Visualforce Actions Send:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_single_email.htm&type=5 , then Contact will not be populated.  Follow the process above and you should see the email send definition have contact populated since it was a direct send.

Since this was sent to a SFDE; the Contact, Lead, Campaign, Report, exclusions...etc would not be populated.

https://ibb.co/vX1QKk1

The IER would hold the individual email results information that would be more applicable to the individual recipient.